# azure function (node) calling mongodb finishes without error but nothing comes back from query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, azure-functions

I have a node function that calls mongo to request some data.  There is no error but it does not seem to connect to mongo and get the data either.  Is there something I'm not doing right?

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
module.exports = async (context, req) => {

try {
    let connectionString = 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@<endpoint>.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true';
    context.log('******************** 11 *************************');
    MongoClient.connect(connectionString, {uri_decode_auth: true}, function(err, client) {
        if (err) {
            context.log('Failed to connect');
            context.res = { status: 500, body: err.message }
            return context.done();
        }
        context.log('******************** 22 *************************');
        client.db("stuff").collection("items").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                context.log('Error running query');
                context.res = { status: 500, body: err.message }
                return context.done();
            }
            context.log(result);
            context.log('******************** 44 *************************');
            let message = "Hello " + req.query.name + ". Have a nice day!.  Really...";
            context.res = {
                status: 200,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: {"message": message}
            };
            context.done();
            client.close();
        });
        });
    }
    catch(error) {
        context.log('caught the error');
        context.log(error)
    }
};
```

The output I see in azure logs is:

```
2018-10-26T12:38:07  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
2018-10-26T12:38:17.218 [Information] Executing 'Functions.zap-search' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', 
Id=e294fde0-d249-4237-a421-e85bde40f843)
2018-10-26T12:38:17.715 [Information] ******************** 11 *************************
2018-10-26T12:38:18.461 [Information] Executed 'Functions.zap-search' (Succeeded, Id=e294fde0-d249-4237-a421-e85bde40f843)
```

Comment: Is there a timeout to connect mongodb? What if the `connect` call gets stuck for quite some time?

Comment: azure functions have a 5 minute timeout.  as you can see from the log trace there is less than a second between the '** 11 **' log statement and the function completing.  I can also connect through robomongo without problem with same connection details.  According to mongo docs, if a timeout is not set in connection string the default is to not timeout (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using V2 of Azure functions you need to decide if you are going to be using promises or callbacks. The code you posted is callback based but exported as a promise because of the use `async` keyword and since the MongoClient.connect is not awaited the runtime exits your function before executing these results.
If you remove the `async` keyword should start seeing the desired results.